# Syntax for Ember multiselect

Tags: ember.js, multi-select

Syntax tried so far for multiselect is below, i.e included multiple="multiple"

```html
{{view Ember.Select multiple="multiple"
    contentBinding="App.viewPersonController"
    selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
    optionLabelPath="content.personName"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    prompt="Select..." }}
{{/view}}
```

Below is the error:

Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Select multiple is false, but you have specified an Array selection.

how to make multiple **true**?

Answer (score 3):

Beside the issue with your Handlebars template - `{{view}}` must not be closed with an end tag, but `{{#view}}{{/view}}` needs to - your provided code works fine. `multiple` is a boolean so everything which evaluates to `true` will set it to `true`. That's why assigning `multiple` works too. I also removed the `prompt` since it messes up multiple selections. I guess this is a bug. See http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/p4QfQ/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{view Ember.Select
    multiple="true"
    contentBinding="App.viewPersonController"
    selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.persons"
    optionLabelPath="content.personName"
    optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.viewPersonController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [{personName: 'Alf', id: 1}, {personName: 'Brian', id: 2}]
});

App.selectedPersonController = Ember.Object.create({
    persons: []
});​
```

---

A note on the `view` Handlebars helper: if you specify a view via `{{view ClassName}}` you are telling Handlebars to render the specific view `ClassName`, where the template is defined as `templateName` or precompiled as `template` on the views' class.

By declaring a view via `{{#view ClassName}} template instructions {{/view}}` you are defining the template for the view which shall be rendered explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the helper clarification and it fixed the issue