# Multiple selects instead of multi select in Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

in Ember multiselects can be created using the `multiple` property of the `Ember.Select` view (e.g. in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275695/syntax-for-ember-multiselect)).

What I want to do is substituting a multiselect with multiple "normal" selects, which are all bound to the same array. Let's say I have two single selects, then both should be bound to an array `fooArray`. When I select *foo* in the first select and *bar* in the second one, then `fooArray` should be `['foo', 'bar']`.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can set a selectionBinding for each select and a computed property taha makes the array... sure there are better ways to do this... it depends of the number of selects you deal with, because, in this example, the returned array is recalculated each time you get it
and this don't scale very well

```
App.SelectionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    select1Value:null,
    select2Value:null,
    select3Value:null,
    selectedArray:function{
        return Ember.Array(this.get('select1Value'),this.get('select2Value'),this.get('select2Value'));
    }.property('select1Value','select2Value','select3Value')

});
```

In the view

```
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="YourSelectContent"
    selectionBinding="App.SelectionController.select1Value"
[...]
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="YourSelectContent"
    selectionBinding="App.SelectionController.select2Value"
[...]
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="YourSelectContent"
    selectionBinding="App.SelectionController.select3Value"
[...]
```